# DirectX12 rendering to part of the window

Tags: windows, directx-12

I am trying to have the DirectX12 pipeline render to only part of the window, not the full window. Is that even possible?
I can manually translate the vertices, or set the screenViewport to be a smaller size, but the renderer still renders to the whole window, setting a background color to that which is unrendered.

Even if I set the backbuffers size to be the smaller size, the target view is still the whole window. How can I change the target view to be just a part of the window?

I must be missing something about `CreateRenderTargetView()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass [`D3D12_RECT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/d3d12-rect) to [`ClearRenderTargetView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12/nf-d3d12-id3d12graphicscommandlist-clearrendertargetview) to specify what portion of a render target to clear. So set your viewport of smaller size, clear only that part and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you, I knew I missed something simple!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it, just configure scissor-rect and viewport-rect for the region you are interested in.